# Numpy Array Slicing using a polygon in Matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, polygon, slice, astronomy

This seems like a fairly straightforward problem, but I'm new to Python and I'm struggling to resolve it.  I've got a scatter plot / heatmap generated from two numpy arrays (about 25,000 pieces of information).  The y-axis is taken directly from an array and the x-axis is generated from a simple subtraction operation on two arrays.

What I need to do now is slice up the data so that I can work with a selection that falls within certain parameters on the plot.  For example, I need to extract all the points that fall within the parallelogram:
[image]

I'm able to cut out a rectangle using simple inequalities (see indexing `idx_c`, `idx_h` and `idx`, below) but I really need a way to select the points using a more complex geometry.  It looks like this slicing can be done by specifying the vertices of the polygon.  This is about the closest I can find to a solution, but I can't figure out how to implement it:

http://matplotlib.org/api/nxutils_api.html#matplotlib.nxutils.points_inside_poly

Ideally, I really need something akin to the indexing below, i.e. something like `colorjh[idx]`.  Ultimately I'll have to plot different quantities (for example, `colorjh[idx]` vs `colorhk[idx]`), so the indexing needs to be transferable to all the arrays in the dataset (lots of arrays).  Maybe that's obvious, but I would imagine there are solutions that might not be as flexible.  In other words, I'll use this plot to select the points I'm interested in, and then I'll need those indices to work for other arrays from the same table.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import atpy
from pylab import *

twomass = atpy.Table()

twomass.read('/IRSA_downloads/2MASS_GCbox1.tbl')

hmag = list([twomass['h_m']])
jmag = list([twomass['j_m']])
kmag = list([twomass['k_m']])

hmag = np.array(hmag)
jmag = np.array(jmag)
kmag = np.array(kmag)

colorjh = np.array(jmag - hmag)
colorhk = np.array(hmag - kmag)

idx_c = (colorjh > -1.01) & (colorjh < 6)  #manipulate x-axis slicing here here
idx_h = (hmag > 0) & (hmag < 17.01)        #manipulate y-axis slicing here
idx = idx_c & idx_h

# heatmap below
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(hmag[idx], colorjh[idx], bins=200)
extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[-1], xedges[0]]
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent, aspect=0.65)

plt.xlabel('Color(J-H)', fontsize=15)           #adjust axis labels here
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (H)', fontsize=15)

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()       #I put this in to recover familiar axis orientation

plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.title('CMD for Galactic Center (2MASS)', fontsize=20)
plt.grid(True)
colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Like I say, I'm new to Python, so the less jargon-y the explanation the more likely I'll be able to implement it.  Thanks for any help y'all can provide.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but your lines: `mag = list([twomass['m']]); mag = np.array(mag)` can be combined: `mag = np.array([twomass['m']])` without the intermediate `list`, which would be slower and waste memory. Also, `jmag - hmag` will already be an array, so no need to call `np.array(jmag - hmag)`.

Comment: as a side note, if you are worried about ensuring things are arrays `np.asarray` is nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100))

x = np.linspace(-1,5.5,100) # tried to mimic your data boundaries
y = np.linspace(8,16,100)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

m = np.all([yy > xx**2, yy < 10* xx, xx < 4, yy > 9], axis = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Would you be able to explain what's going on with the meshgrid and np.logical_and lines?  It looks like an elegant solution but I can't make out how to work this into my code.

A quick try yielded a ValueError: "total size of new array must be unchanged."  The arrays I'm working with are all single-values... they're not matrices.  If that makes any sense.

Comment: Instead of my `x` and `y` vectors, use your `h` and `h-j` arrays.  You can't have just one index for each `h` vector because the slice in `h` depends on which value in `h-j` you're looking at, because it's not rectangular, so you need to make a 2d-matrix after all.